# how to make a jquery vertical slider move continue

Tags: jquery

I am new here and i really need your advise. I have a jquery vertical slider and I have 2 problems:

1. it is stopping after last row
2. when i put mouse over one cell it doesn't stop.

Here is the code:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.vertigo = function(options) {

    $(this).addClass("vertigo");
    var list = $('.vertigo li');
    var totallist = list.length;

    $(this).after('<a href="#pre" class="btn-pre"><img src="prev.png"/></a> <a href="#next" class="btn-next"><img src="next.png"/></a>');
    $('.vertigo li').each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass("item"+(i+1));
    });

    var total = 1;

    // Settings
    var settings = $.extend({
        play  : true,
        timer : 1000
    }, options);

    if ( settings.play ) {
        var playx = settings.play;  
    }       
    if ( settings.timer ) {
        var timerx = settings.timer;    
    }

    if(playx == true){
        setInterval(function() {

            if ( total <= (totallist - 1)) {
                var nlisth = $('.item'+total).outerHeight();
                $('.vertigo li').animate({'top':'-='+nlisth+'px'}); 
                total++;
                //console.log(total);
            }else{

                $('.vertigo li')=1;


            }
        }, timerx);
    }

    $('.btn-pre').click(function(){
        var plisth = $('.item'+(total-1)).outerHeight();
        if ( total !== 1 && total <= totallist) {
            total--;
            $('.vertigo li').animate({'top':'+='+plisth+'px'});
        }
    });

    $('.btn-next').click(function(){
        var nlisth = $('.item'+total).outerHeight();
        if ( total <= (totallist - 1)) {
            total++;
            $('.vertigo li').animate({'top':'-='+nlisth+'px'});
        }
    }); 

  }

  return false;

}(jQuery));
```